# Creating and adding to arrays within a program -- Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm a fairly new Ruby user and I was wondering how you create and edit arrays within a program.  I'm making a sentence-generator-type program where you can add to arrays of nouns, verbs, and other sentence parts, but I'm currently not sure how to make the arrays in the first place.
Here's the code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/ruby Make_a_Sentence!


#This will eventually create the sentence
    def makeSent (*arg)
        for i in 0...arg.length
            print arg[i].sample if arg[i].kind_of?(Array)
            print arg[i] if arg[i].kind_of?(String)
        end
    end

#this is supposed to add to the array (it's not working)
    def addWord (array, word)
        if array.kind_of?(Array)
            array.push(word)
            puts "#{ word } added to #{ array }"
        else
            puts "#{ array } does not exist"
        end
    end

#This is supposed to create the arrays
    def addType (name)
        @name = Array.new
        puts "#{ name } created"
    end

    while 1 > 0
        input = gets
        $words = input.split
        if $words[0] == "addWord" && $words.length == 3
            addWord($words[1], $words[2])
        end
        if $words[0] == "addType" && $words.length == 2
            addType($words[1])
        end
    end
```

**Sorry!  I guess I didn't phrase the question well enough!  I was mainly wondering how to create new arrays while the program is running, but the arrays have specific names that are given.  I actually ended up just using hashes for this, but thanks for the responses nonetheless!

Answer (score 0):

Making an `Array` is done like so:

```
array = ["val1","val2","val3"] 
array = %w{value value value} 
 # The second example is a shorthand syntax (splits values with just a space)
```

Familiarize yourself with the documentation: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html

Also when you're using methods like: `def makeSent (*arg)` just be aware that `*args` with the `*` in front of it - is what's called a `splat`. Which means this method takes many arguments without the `[]` syntax and automatically converts all of the arguments into an array for you.

So you would call this method like: `makeSent (first, second, third, etc)`

Answer (score 0):

Creating arrays is easy: simply enclose the objects in square brackets, like so:

```
my_array = [12, 29, 36, 42]
another_array = ['something', 64, 'another', 1921]
```

Notice you can mix and match types within the array. If you want to add items to the end of the array, you can use `<<` to do it:

```
my_array = [1, 3, 5, 7]
my_array << 9
# my_array is now: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

You can access and modify specific items within the array by indexing it within square brackets:

```
my_array[2]  # <-- this will be  5, as arrays are 0-indexed
my_array[2] = 987
# my_array is now [1, 3, 987, 7, 9]
```

There are a lot of great methods for accessing, modifying, and comparing arrays that you can [find in the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html).